# Why exactly are void* bad in C++? What alternatives are there?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project to implement [this Multi-Join algorithm](http://www.frankmcsherry.org/dataflow/relational/join/2015/04/11/genericjoin.html). The code I had in mind looks something like this:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
vector<tuple<A,B,C>> multi_join(vector<pair<A,B>> R1, vector<pair<B,C>> R2, vector<pair<A,C>> R3)
{
    void* existing = new vector<tuple<>>;
    void* p1, p2, p3;
    
    p1 = &propose<A>(R1, *(vector<tuple<>>*) existing); // Returns vector<tuple<A>>
    p2 = &propose<A>(R2, *(vector<tuple<>>*) existing);
    p3 = &propose<A>(R3, *(vector<tuple<>>*) existing);

    existing = &intersect(*(vector<tuple<A>>*) p1, *(vector<tuple<A>>*) p2, *(vector<tuple<A>>*) p3);
    
    p1 = &propose<B>(R1, *(vector<tuple<A>>*) existing); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B>>
    p2 = &propose<B>(R2, *(vector<tuple<A>>*) existing);
    p3 = &propose<B>(R3, *(vector<tuple<A>>*) existing);

    existing = &intersect(*(vector<tuple<A, B>>*) p1, *(vector<tuple<A, B>>*) p2, *(vector<tuple<A, B>>*) p3);

    p1 = &propose<C>(R1, *(vector<tuple<A, B>>*) existing); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B, C>>
    p2 = &propose<C>(R2, *(vector<tuple<A, B>>*) existing);
    p3 = &propose<C>(R3, *(vector<tuple<A, B>>*) existing);

    existing = &intersect(*(vector<tuple<A, B, C>>*) p1, *(vector<tuple<A, B, C>>*) p2, *(vector<tuple<A, B, C>>*) p3);

    return *(vector<tuple<A, B, C>>*) existing;
}
```

Note how `existing` must go from being of type `vector<tuple<>>` to `vector<tuple<A>>` to `vector<tuple<A, B>>` and finally to `vector<tuple<A, B, C>>`. This is a limited example, but the idea is to eventually make it so there can be any amount of input vectors.

I've looked into how I can try to do this, and `void*` seems to be the easiest way, but I've also come across sources saying it is bad code.

What alternative do I have? Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: This is not just "bad code", this is UB and will most probably crash: `*(vector<tuple<A>>*) existing` (reading/writing to the result of this dereference, not the cast itself).

Comment: The code is type erasing and then casting to a different type.  I can't see how this can be anything else  other then Undefined Behaviour

Comment: `void*` basically takes you out of the type system.  You have know, somehow, what that `void*` actually points to and hat is a real pain.  As is, all of this code has undefined behavior as you can't just treat a `vector<tuple<>>` as a `vector<tuple<A,B,C>>`.

Comment: The right way is to write generic code based on templates.

Comment: void can be safe to use with dumb buffers like char a[100] if you know what you are doing, but with classes and structs that manage their memory it's rarely going to work like you want it to.  Casts don't magically convert data they just change the code's view of the data.

Comment: `*(vector<tuple<A, B>>*)` and friends are [Explicit Casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). They are the Word of God to the compiler. Whatever you're doing, no matter how smart or how stupid, the compiler will accept. It turns off all of its brains and does exactly what you told it to do. There are no warnings. There are no errors. If you don't know exactly what you are doing, odds are good you've traded a compiler error for a much harder to find and deal with runtime error.

Comment: My rule of thumb is if I see one of these puppies in code and its purpose is not immediately obvious, casting a buffer to `char` in a stream write for example, I approach the code assuming it's wrong and start looking for the bug. Even if testing has not yet shown any bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At any and all lines in your code, the type of `existing` is known and fixed.

```
auto va1 = propose<A>(R1, std::vector<std::tuple<>>{}); // Returns vector<tuple<A>>
auto va2 = propose<A>(R2, std::vector<std::tuple<>>{});
auto va3 = propose<A>(R3, std::vector<std::tuple<>>{});

auto AIntersect = intersect(va1, va2, va3);

auto vab1 = propose<B>(R1, AIntersect); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B>>
auto vab2 = propose<B>(R2, AIntersect); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B>>
auto vab3 = propose<B>(R3, AIntersect); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B>>

auto ABIntersect = intersect(vab1, vab2, vab3);

auto vabc1 = propose<c>(R1, ABIntersect); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B, C>>
auto vabc2 = propose<c>(R2, ABIntersect); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B, C>>
auto vabc3 = propose<C>(R3, ABIntersect); // Returns vector<tuple<A, B, C>>

auto ABCIntersect = intersect(vabc1, vabc2, vabc3);
return ABCIntersect;
```

This no longer takes pointers to return values of functions (ick), and gives everything its proper type name.  It is also much shorter.

As an aside, if you **ever** do `new std::vector` there is a 99.9% chance your code is incorrectly designed.  `std::vector` manages a buffer of data on the heap, putting it on the heap is almost always a sign you are screwing up and mindlessly replacing `new int[100]` with `new std::vector<int>`.

Your code called `new` and never called `delete`; it leaked.

Your code took the address of the return value of `intersect` and `propose`.  Who owns that memory?  I have no clue; it was probably dangling and your code did UB.

So I changed it to `auto` and store the `std::vector` to manage the heap allocated return value cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense to me. I never called delete because this wasn't my actual code, just giving an example. I can see the utility of using auto and to be fair I actually can't remember why I called 'new std::vector'.

The one issue that I'm not sure is resolved is the fact that (in the long run) I won't know how many intersects I might have to do, and creating a new variable with a new name each time hardly seems doable.

That is what I was trying to achieve by using a void*, I essentially wanted a variable to keep track of results endlessly until the program was done.

Comment: @MarcoT The `auto` just makes it briefer.  At each line we know the type of every variable, because we are about to call another function which needs to know that type.  And in 999/1000 cases, you can tell the compiler what the type is, and it can check and dispatch for you.  Variables don't really have a cost.  You can usually scope them so there are only a limited number around, or even just refactor the operation so they don't even exist in your function.

Answer (score 4):

> Why exactly are `void*` bad in C++? What alternatives are there?

Types and pointers to types which acts as helpers. `void*` removes (or acts as a detergent to) the type system.

"*Why exactly are `void*` bad*" - because they make everything harder to control. To take it one step further, why have a type system at all? It *is* possible to do everything C++ can do *without* C++. C++ is an abstraction meant to help.